# Ommit 'Press any key' when transfering input '<' Batch

Tags: batch-file, file-io, io, compare

I have a program that takes some variables and prints something on the screen. I want to use a **batch script** to transfer the input from a **file** to the console and then to another file.

So for example my program takes the number **1** and outputs **2**. I have a bunch of test files and test results that I want to compare. For example **test1.txt** contains 1, test2.txt - 2, and **result1.txt** contains 2, results2.txt contains 3. But when using

```
program.exe < test1.txt > test.txt
```

(in order to later **compare** it with result1.txt) the output in test.txt is

```
2
Press any key to continue...
```

Is there a way to ommit this 'Press any key to continue...', when the result is only '2' I can't compare the two?

Comment: "So for example my program takes the number 1 and outputs 2" is program.exe your program? in that case, remove the "press any key to continue".

Comment: Are you using a `pause` statement in your batch file? Or is this message printed by your exe file?

Comment: hard to tell, because we don't know your exe. But you may try `type test1.txt |program.exe >test.txt`

Comment: Another idea: put a second (empty) line to "test1.txt" to feed an additional <enter> to your program

Comment: Wow, no, it turns out that I've thought that the problem is in the batch file but actually the program is made in C++ and has a system("pause"); at the end.. (facepalm) This question is due to be deleted..

Comment: ok, then my "another idea" should solve your problem.